# ld cannot find math library

Tags: ld, dynamic-linking

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and am having trouble linking to the math functions (from ). I have gcc installed and able to compile the source fine. However, trying:

```
gcc -lm montecarlo_time.o parsercfile.o -o trmcfl
```

Gives several errors of the form:

```
montecarlo_time.o: In function `main:
/home/karthik/Research/MC/trmcfl/Dumps/whiteScaling/18-Sep-2012/montecarlo_time.c:75: undefined reference to asin`
```

However, all of these files are present (and visible to ldconfig -v -N)

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
/lib64/libm.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xen/libm.a
/usr/lib64/libm.a
/usr/lib64/libm.so
```

Why is the linking failing?

Comment: what happens when you compile [this](http://pastebin.com/Mze88wet) code.

Comment: Compiles fine -- no errors.

gcc -c -Wall montecarlo_time.c
montecarlo_time.c: In function ‘newpath’:
montecarlo_time.c:333:28: warning: variable ‘nextlayer_ref_index’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
montecarlo_time.c:332:42: warning: variable ‘stepy’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
montecarlo_time.c:332:35: warning: variable ‘stepx’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

gcc -c -Wall parsercfile.c

Answer (score 2):

you should use `-lm` at the end.

because unresolved symbols are found after gcc encounters `montecarlo_time.o` and there is no library or anything else in which it can find it can resolve that symbol.

Comment: That worked! Still don't follow why the linker cannot resolve calls to math.h functions, if -lm was the first option to gcc.

Comment: It's a longstanding limitation of the way symbols are resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I have *always* typed `gcc -lm file.c`;  Until the most recent version of Ubuntu, this worked. On the internet, I see suggestions that it's bad style, but it works. It seems this has now changed.